# SQL bmi equation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to calculate the BMI, rounded up to three digits, of the student in my table:

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| fname | weight | height |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Mark  | 72.90  |    181 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

The height is recorded in centimeters. The formula for BMI is kg/m^2.
Here is my formula:

```
ROUND(weight/(height/100)^2,3) AS BMI
```

If I take that "^2" out of the equation it doesn't return NULL but it is the wrong answer, otherwise returns NULL all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^`  does not do what you think. It is the [Bitwise XOR operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor), that is meant to perform binary operations on binary values.

Use [`power()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_power) instead of `^`:

```
ROUND(weight / POWER(height / 100, 2), 3) AS BMI
```

I am unsure about `height/100`. The usual computation for BMI is just:

```
ROUND((weight / POWER(height, 2), 3)
```

Or you can just multiply:

```
ROUND((weight / (height * height), 3)
```

Comment: You are a genius, I didn't even know there is something like that in SQL, that's why I'm learning tho :).

Comment: The `height/100` was for converting centimetres in metres

Comment: this is for Kg/cm ???

Answer (score 0):

weight / power(height / 100.0, 2) >= 30 THEN obese